# MinGW make fails on crlibm: 'failcom' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: makefile, mingw

On Windows 7, 64-bit, I am trying to compile [crlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/). My environment is a 32-bit MinGW that came with the Python-XY distribution, and the shell I'm using is bash as it comes with Git for Windows.

I have sucessfully ran `./configure` without any arguments. But when I try to run `make`, I get the following error message:

```
$ env PATH=/c/MinGW32-xy/bin make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `c:/Users/michael/crlibm-1.0beta4'
'failcom' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory `c:/Users/michael/crlibm-1.0beta4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As someone noticed [in a different context](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/200911/0141.html), `failcom` seems to be a variable in the makefile, but for some reason it is interpreted as a command. When this command is invoked, it is of course not found, and the build process fails.

Unfortunately, the discussion linked above has not led to a solution that I could have used. So my question is if anyone here recognizes this problem and knows how to solve or work around it.

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer to my question on [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) wiki page. I cite:

> A common misunderstanding is MSYS is "UNIX on Windows", MSYS by itself does not contain a compiler or a C library, therefore does not give the ability to magically port UNIX programs over to Windows nor does it provide any UNIX specific functionality like case-sensitive filenames. Users looking for such functionality should look to Cygwin or Microsoft's Interix instead.

To summarize: MSYS/MinGW is not suposed to support a configure/make workflow of the type a UNIX user is accustomed to. Installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) as suggested in the above wiki page did indeed solve my problem.